# Hibernate inserting null values in table with One To Many mapping and Oracle Sequence

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have two tables Employee and Department where I am trying to persist Department data through OneToMany mapping. When i do save data is inserting into Department table and Employee table but the deptid in Employee table updating with null value. Can any one Please help me on this?

Below are my classes,mapping files and configuration file.

```
public class Department {
    private int deptid;
    private String deptname;
    private Set<Employee> empSet;
    public int getDeptid() {
        return deptid;
    }
    public void setDeptid(int deptid) {
        this.deptid = deptid;
    }
    public String getDeptname() {
        return deptname;
    }
    public void setDeptname(String deptname) {
        this.deptname = deptname;
    }
    public Set<Employee> getEmpSet() {
        return empSet;
    }
    public void setEmpSet(Set<Employee> empSet) {
        this.empSet = empSet;
    }
}

public class Employee {

    private String empname;
    private int empid;
    private int salary;
    private int age;
    private int deptid;
    private String gender;
    public int getDeptid() {
        return deptid;
    }
    public void setDeptid(int deptid) {
        this.deptid = deptid;
    }
    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
    public void setSalary(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }
    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }
    public String getEmpname() {
        return empname;
    }
    public void setEmpname(String empname) {
        this.empname = empname;
    }
    public int getEmpid() {
        return empid;
    }
    public void setEmpid(int empid) {
        this.empid = empid;
    }

}


public class RunDemo {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.configure("com/hibernate/OneToMany/hibernate.cfg.xml");
        SessionFactory factory = conf.buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        Employee emp1 = new  Employee();
        emp1.setEmpname("Sowmya");
        emp1.setAge(26);
        emp1.setGender("F");
        emp1.setSalary(77600);

        Employee emp2 = new  Employee();
        emp2.setEmpname("Raju");
        emp2.setAge(29);
        emp2.setGender("M");
        emp2.setSalary(67600);

        Employee emp3 = new  Employee();
        emp3.setEmpname("Shyam");
        emp3.setAge(30);
        emp3.setGender("M");
        emp3.setSalary(37600);

        Set<Employee> employeeSet = new HashSet<Employee>();
        employeeSet.add(emp1);
        employeeSet.add(emp3);
        employeeSet.add(emp2);

        Department department = new Department();
        department.setDeptid(55);
        department.setDeptname("TestDept");
        department.setEmpSet(employeeSet);

        session.save(department);

        transaction.commit();
        session.close();


    }

}
```

Department mapping file:

```
 <hibernate-mapping>
     <class name="com.hibernate.OneToMany.Department" table="DEPARTMENT" schema="TEST"> 
        <id name="deptid" type="int">
            <column name="deptid" precision="5" scale="0" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <set name="empSet" table="EMPLOYEE" cascade="all">
            <key column="deptid"></key>
            <one-to-many class="com.hibernate.OneToMany.Employee"/>
        </set>
        <property name="deptname" length="50" type="string" column="deptname"></property>
     </class>
 </hibernate-mapping>
```

Employee mapping file:

```
 <hibernate-mapping>
     <class name="com.hibernate.OneToMany.Employee" table="EMPLOYEE" schema="TEST"> 
        <id name="empid" type="int">
            <column name="empid" precision="5" scale="0" />
            <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">EMPID_SEQ</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <property name="empname" length="50" type="string" column="empname"></property>
        <property name="salary" type="int" column="salary"></property>
        <property name="age" type="int" column="age"></property>
        <property name="gender" length="2" type="string" column="gender"></property>
     </class>
 </hibernate-mapping>


CREATE TABLE "TEST"."EMPLOYEE" 
   (    "EMPID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "EMPNAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "DEPTID" NUMBER, 
    "SALARY" NUMBER, 
    "AGE" NUMBER, 
    "GENDER" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "VER" NUMBER, 
    "EMPLOYMENT_TYPE" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "CODE" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE), 
     CONSTRAINT "EMPLOYEE_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("EMPID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "EMPLOYEE_FK1" FOREIGN KEY ("DEPTID")
      REFERENCES "TEST"."DEPARTMENT" ("DEPTID") ENABLE
   ) PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;




  CREATE TABLE "TEST"."DEPARTMENT" 
   (    "DEPTID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "DEPTNAME" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
     CONSTRAINT "DEPARTMENT_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("DEPTID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE
   ) PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your employee hbm.xml file requires this:

```
<many-to-one name="deptid" class="com.hibernate.OneToMany.Department" fetch="select">
     <column name="DEPTID" not-null="true" />
</many-to-one>
```

Otherwise, hibernate has no indication that a `deptid` exists in the `Employee` objects.

Comment: I am getting the following error when i add the above code.

Hibernate: select EMPID_SEQ.nextval from dual
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of com.hibernate.OneToMany.Department.deptid

Comment: So it looks like your column name is actually "DEPTID" not "DEPT_ID" as I've given above. Please try that.

Comment: If that doesn't work, please provide the code you've used to create the departments/employees before saving.